# How to check a class contains property of another class in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a class like -

```
class AClass {
  public int P1 { get; set; }
  public string P2 { get; set; }
  public string P3 { get; set; }
}
```

Another class like -

```
class BClass {
  public int P1 { get; set; }
  public string P2{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to check check if class `AClass`  contains(should match both name and type) properties of `BClass` or not. How can do that?

Comment: can you define what you mean by "contains properties of another class" ? a Property with the same name / type? ... a Property with the type of the other class? maybe give the expected output of your example

Comment: both name and type

Comment: so you expect the answer to your example to be P1 and P2 ?

Comment: Yes @DarkSquirrel42 . As it match both property name and type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way of testing this with reflection could be this:

```
var propertiesOfA = typeof(AClass).GetProperties();
var propertiesOfB = typeof(BClass).GetProperties();

var commonProperties = propertiesOfB.Where(
    b => propertiesOfA.Any(
        a => 
            b.Name == a.Name 
            && b.PropertyType == a.PropertyType
        )
    ).ToArray();
```

Comment: What was wrong with my answer? That you left this answer?

Comment: uhm... probably nothing ... it just was not there when I loaded the page? ... I mean ... 4 minutes apart ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection on the types and find the properties with the same name & type

```
var commonProperties = 
    typeof(AClass).GetProperties().Join(typeof(BClass).GetProperties(),                
    prop => new {prop.PropertyType, prop.Name},
    prop => new {prop.PropertyType, prop.Name},
            (propA, propB)=>propA.Name);
```

Do note however, that code snippet only checks for Name & Type. There are dozens of other things that could be different, like availability of get, set, attributes,..

Answer (score 0):

You could solve tis using reflection :

```
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;
myPropertyInfo = Type.GetType("System.Type").GetProperties();
Console.WriteLine("Properties of System.Type are:");
for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myPropertyInfo[i].ToString());
}
```

Read more at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can check the properties of the two classes and select these names.

```
   var duplicates = typeof(AClass).GetProperties().Where(a => typeof(BClass).GetProperties().Any(b => b.Name == a.Name && b.PropertyType == a.PropertyType)).Select(x => x.Name);
```